# erro ao aplicação no homolog

Tags: sql

Bom dia,

Eu estou passando um problema na versão homolog do projeto

```
The index 'IX_ReqCompraId_Id' is dependent on column 'ReqCompraId'.
The object 'FK_dbo.Pedidos_dbo.ReqCompra_ReqCompraId' is dependent on column 'ReqCompraId'.
The object 'FK_dbo.Pedidos_dbo.ItemRC_ReqCompraId_Id' is dependent on column 'ReqCompraId'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ReqCompraId failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Ja tentei fazer os seguintes comandos para mudar o nome de Id2 para id mas continua sem sucesso

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pedidos] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Pedidos]
GO 


EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Pedidos.Id2', @newname = N'Id', @objtype = N'COLUMN' 


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pedidos] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Pedidos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ReqCompraId_Id] ON [dbo].[Pedidos]
(
    [ReqCompraId] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Para excluir a coluna primeiro precisa remover as dependências.  A mensagem é bem clara, precisa excluir o índice *IX_ReqCompraId_Id*, as *constraints* de FK, pelo nome provavelmente nas tabelas *ReqCompra* e *ItemRC*

Comment: Mas esse erro ocorre quando eu tento executar a aplicação

Comment: Mas no final da mensagem de erro tem *"ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ReqCompraId failed because one or more objects access this column."*, ou seja, o erro aconteceu por conta de um DROP COLOMN

Comment: Sua aplicação usando algum ORM como *Entity Framework* ou *Hibernate*?

Comment: Estou usando entity @RicardoPontual

Comment: Entendi ai faz sentido. Provavelmente a coluna foi excluída do modelo, o quando o Entity está tentando sincronizar com a base de dados, está dando esse erro ao executar a aplicação

Comment: Foi excluida onde que você fala, no sql?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79396/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-ricardo-pontual).